# What happened to the "deleter" in Metroid: Other M?

Tags: metroid-other-m

I finished *Metroid: Other M* (I know, my first mistake) but the story line about the "deleter" never really resolved. Does anyone knew what happened to that guy?

Comment: The sad thing is, it's an absolutely fine game (not stellar, but not *bad*) if you completely block out the plot and voice acting!

Comment: @RavenDreamer When considered by itself, sure, it's an okay game, but when considering the three fantastic Metroid Prime games that proceeded it, and the rest of the better games in the series, it's just a big ol' disappointment.

Comment: @Fambida To be fair, the prime games were a different company (Retro Studios; Other M was Team Ninja)

Comment: I liked Other M...

Comment: Other M wasn't terrible, but the story was pretty weak

Comment: The problem with Other M is that it was too shallow. Metroid games are known for depth and detail, but I completed Other M 100% in 8 hours without any guides or help, and about half of that time was spent watching cinemas.

Comment: I don't know what you guys are talking about, Metroid: Other M is clearly the best game of all time.  http://www.ign.com/boards/threads/metroid-other-m-is-the-best-game-of-all-time.452814005/  Clearly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah that subplot is mostly left dangling for no real reason. There is decent evidence as to how it ended though.

> When Samus is lead to the Bioweapons Research Center, she meets MB. After Samus leaves at the end of the cutscene someone from the 07th Platoon comes in (one can assume this is the Deleter) and gets a shot at MB. When Samus returns to the room later in the game, James Pierce is seen dead on the spot.

Source: http://www.metroidwiki.org/wiki/The_Deleter

Comment: It is pretty certain who it is.  It turns out that you see a piece of equipment on his arm.  Only one member of the team has that particular equipment.